# Android Programming How to Get XML String Ordered Tags

Tags: android, tags, xmlserializer, stringwriter

I wrote This Code.It works great.But i have a trouble with its output string.

```
   public static String CreateIndexForImage() 
   throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, IOException
{
   String Image_Name = "Bla BLa";

   static XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
   static StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);

   xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);

   xmlSerializer.startTag("", "imagefile");
   xmlSerializer.startTag("", "image");
   xmlSerializer.startTag("", "name");

   xmlSerializer.text(Image_Name);

   xmlSerializer.endTag("", "name");
   xmlSerializer.endTag("", "image");
   xmlSerializer.endTag("", "imagefile"); 

   xmlSerializer.endDocument();

   return writer.toString();
 }
```

The output is like:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><imagefile><image><name>Bla Bla</name></image></imagefile>
```

But i want the output ordered like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
 <imagefile>
      <image>
         <name>Bla BLa</name>
      </image>
 </imagefile>
```

Is there a method or something to write like this in XmlSerializer class or StringWriter class?
Otherwise i can do it another way to order the lines like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like that?

```
serializer.setProperty(
"http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-indentation", "   ");

serializer.setProperty(
"http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/properties.html#serializer-line-separator", "\n");
```

I don't know if this still works. Otherwise you can try something like that:

```
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The second suggestion works fine.I didnt try first at all:)